# ios UILabel white spaces when HTML text is passed in it

Tags: html, ios, objective-c

I have been struggling with an issue for quite long time. The issue is when I pass normal text in UILabel, the label resizes automatically to the text. But when I pass HTML text `(<p>, <li>, <ul>)`, then after the text is completed, there comes a white space of around 1 line in the end of text, causing UILabel to extend its height. I have already tried Autolayout, sizeToFit and other methods.

Comment: Can you please share the html in file format and output in txt file format

Comment: please share the html text which you are set in UILable

Comment: <p><b>To use the health code</b></p><ul class="bullet"><li>You can contact our advisers at 1234 5678 987</li><li>Select the contact and chat Helpline option. Customer Helpline is open 24/7 and the doctor’s Advice Helpline is open Monday to Friday, 9am to 5pm</li></ul>